# Sorting Gridview Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, sortdirection

I have a gridview and i am using paging in it

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   this.BindData();
}
```

Now the problem is that when I click on a header to sort the gridview and then I go to the second page, then come back to the first one, it is not remembering the sort expression DESC or ASC.

How can i persist the direction in which it is being sorted no matter on the page index i click on?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewState to store the SortDirection like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending/415759#415759) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net/702603#702603).

If your `BindData` method also loads the DataSource what it should, you need to sort your datasource by this SortDirection. Change `BindData` so that it takes the SortDirection and PageIndex as parameters.

For example:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   this.BindData(this.SortDirection,e.NewPageIndex); //if SortDirection is a property that returns the ViewState value
}
```

Then sort the Grid's DataSource  and set it's PageIndex there accordingly.