# How to sort the gridview columns by timedate column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Simple gridview.
SqlData source to bind data to gridview.
A column called Date ( type date ) where I add the date when I edited something.

I would like to sort the entire gridview columns by the date column.

Any idea how can I do that?

THanks

Comment: GridView1.Sort(DropdownList1.SelectedValue,SortDirection.Descending) but that's not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As this is a `Page level` problem. So you can first keep the `GridView DataSource` in `ViewState`
2. Keep a hyperlink like control in your header and during `Postback` retrieve the data from `ViewState`. Sort it according to the required parameter . Bind it again to the `GridView`.

Example **[here](http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net)**

Comment: Yea..the problem is that I'm not so advanced in asp.net , if you don't mind showing me some samples or something

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is add an additional column to your SQL select statement. This extra column will be the edit date in a format that can be used for sorting (YYYYMMDD format):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Date], 112) as sortedDate
```

Then change your edit date field to use your sorted date field as the sort expression:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Edit Date" SortExpression="sortedDate"/>
```