# asp.net gridview sorting and paging

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

the problem is if iam sorting with employee field assending or desending it is sorting perfectly if iam pressing next or previous button it is sorting assending order and displaying only in assending order can any body help tp how to bind gridview data at GridView1_PageIndexChanging() event to work perfectly

this is my default3.aspx page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
        CurrentSortField="employeeid" CurrentSortDirection="ASC" 
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" AllowPaging="true" 
        CaptionAlign="Bottom" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onprerender="GridView1_PreRender" 
         PageSize="2">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="Last Name"  
              ItemStyle-Width="15%" SortExpression="EmployeeId" >
<ItemStyle Width="15%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="First Name"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" 
              SortExpression="Name"  >
<ItemStyle Width="15%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-Width="15%" >
<ItemStyle Width="15%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Password"  ItemStyle-Width="15%">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="imgbtn1" runat="server">change password</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="15%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="Date created"  ItemStyle-Width="15%">





<ItemStyle Width="15%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>





</Columns>
        <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/up_arrow.png" Width="10px" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my default.aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
    }

    public static DataSet getallemployees()
    {
        String cs = "Data Source=.;database=users;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblEmployees", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblEmployees", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

    }
    public static List<Employee> GetAllEmployees1(string sortColumn)
    {
        List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();
        String cs = "Data Source=.;database=users;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "select * from tblEmployees";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
            {
                sqlQuery += " order by " + sortColumn;
            }
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Employeeid"]);
                employee.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                employee.Name = rdr["gender"].ToString();
                employee.Name = rdr["city"].ToString();
                listEmployees.Add(employee);


            }
            rdr.Close();

        }
        return listEmployees;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource= GetAllEmployees1("employeeid");
            GridView1.DataBind();
             }
    }
    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        string sortField = string.Empty;
        SortGridview(GridView1, e, out sortDirection, out sortField);
        string strsortDirection = sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        GridView1.DataSource = GetAllEmployees1(e.SortExpression + " " + strsortDirection);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void SortGridview(GridView gridview, GridViewSortEventArgs e, out SortDirection sortDirection, out string sortField)
    {
        sortField = e.SortExpression;
        sortDirection = e.SortDirection;
        if (gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] != null && gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] != null)
        {
            if (sortField == gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortField"])
            {
                if (gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] == "ASC")
                {
                    sortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                }

            }
            gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] = sortField;
            gridview.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] = (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
        }


    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (GridView1.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] != null && GridView1.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] != null)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tableCell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    if (tableCell.HasControls())
                    {
                        LinkButton sortLinkButton = null;
                        if (tableCell.Controls[0] is LinkButton)
                        {
                            sortLinkButton = (LinkButton)tableCell.Controls[0];
                        }
                        if (sortLinkButton != null && GridView1.Attributes["CurrentSortField"] == sortLinkButton.CommandArgument)
                        {
                            Image image = new Image();
                            if (GridView1.Attributes["CurrentSortDirection"] == "ASC")
                            {
                                image.ImageUrl = "~/images/down_arrow.png";
                                image.Width = 10;
                                image.Height = 10;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                image.ImageUrl = "~/images/~/images/up_arrow.png";
                                image.Width = 10;
                                image.Height = 10;
                            }
                            tableCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;"));
                            tableCell.Controls.Add(image);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
    protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Displaying Page " + (GridView1.PageIndex + 1).ToString() + " of " + GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = getallemployees();

        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class viewstate_dataset : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public  DataSet getallemployees
    {
        get{
            if (ViewState["Empdetails"] == null)
            {

                String cs = "Data Source=.;database=users;Integrated Security=SSPI";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblEmployees", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select EmployeeId,Name,gender+','+Name as gender,city from tblEmployees", con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    ViewState["Empdetails"] = ds;
                }
            } return (DataSet)ViewState["Empdetails"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Empdetails"] = value;
        }

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = getallemployees;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Session["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Descending;
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
         string sortexp=e.SortExpression;
         Session["sortexp"] = sortexp;
         if (Session["sortDirection"] != null && Session["sortDirection"].ToString() == SortDirection.Descending.ToString())
         {
             Session["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
             sort (sortexp, "ASC");
         }
         else
         {

             Session["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Descending;
             sort(sortexp, "DESC");

         }

    }
    private void sort(string soreExpression, string p)
    {
        DataView dv = null;
        dv = new DataView(getallemployees.Tables[0]);
        dv.Sort = soreExpression + " " + p;
        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExp = string.Empty;
        string NewSortDirection = string.Empty;
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        if (Session["sortexp"] != null)
        {
            sortExp = (string)Session["sortexp"];
            if (Session["sortDirection"] != null && Session["sortDirection"].ToString() == SortDirection.Ascending.ToString())
            {
                NewSortDirection = "ASC";
            }
            else
            {
                NewSortDirection = "DESC";
            }
            sort(sortExp, NewSortDirection);
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = getallemployees;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Attributes["sortexp"] != null && Session["sortDirection"] != null)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tableCell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    if (tableCell.HasControls())
                    {
                        LinkButton sortLinkButton = null;
                        if (tableCell.Controls[0] is LinkButton)
                        {
                            sortLinkButton = (LinkButton)tableCell.Controls[0];
                        }
                        if (sortLinkButton != null && Session["sortexp"].ToString() == sortLinkButton.CommandArgument)
                        {
                            Image image = new Image();
                            if (Session["sortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
                            {
                                image.ImageUrl = "~/images/down_arrow.png";
                                image.Width = 10;
                                image.Height = 10;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                image.ImageUrl = "~/images/up_arrow.png";
                                image.Width = 10;
                                image.Height = 10;
                            }
                            tableCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;"));
                            tableCell.Controls.Add(image);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but while sort data uparrow and down arrow is not coming on the header columns pls any body help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `getallemployees()` on `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` function which ofcourse is returning unsorted data for next page.

In order to resolve this issue, you need to use `ViewState` for your data to be persistant.

Following solution will greatly help you out in `sorting your grid using ViewState`

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net?rq=1