# Cannot Sort GridView after using DataBind()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, data-binding

I have a `GridView` that already fetches some data from a `SqlDataSource`.

The `GridView` has **sorting**, **paging**, **selection** allowed.

Now when I'm clicking a `button`, I'm creating a new `DataSource` with a new Query, and I'm assigning the new `DataSource` to this Grid, then I use `.DataBind()` to update this grid, but after that, I cannot sort any column.

**Dynamically Creating the new DataSource**

```
SqlDataSource data = new SqlDataSource();
data.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;
data.ProviderName = SqlDataSource1.ProviderName;
data.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
GridView2.DataSourceID = "";
GridView2.DataSource = data;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

I tried to use the following:

```
GridView2.AllowSorting = true;
```

Still it didn't work, this is the error I get.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: after gridview sorting datasource not found so its will be occur.i faced this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the reason for changing the SQLDataSource is because you want to execute a new query on the click of a button; you can do this without creating a new data source:

```
protected void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // dsYourDataSource is the SQLDataSource that is already connected to your gridview
   dsYourDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
   yourGridView.DataBind();
}
```

This might help.

Comment: Yes that's all I wanted to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you set AllowPaging="true" or AllowSorting="true" on a GridView control without using a DataSourceControl DataSource (i.e. SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource), you will run into the following errors:

When changing the page on the GridView control:

```
The GridView 'GridViewID' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.
```

When clicking a column name to sort the column on the GridView control:

```
The GridView 'GridViewID' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.
```

As a result of not setting the DataSourceID property of the GridView to a DataSourceControl DataSource, you have to add event handlers for sorting and paging.

The answer in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net) SO question may help you.

Also I have once used [**this custom control**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18047/Implementation-of-paging-and-sorting-for-the-GridV) in one my projects. You can download the libarary from the link and use custom GridViewEx control. It works well. It will look same as real one:

```
<cc:GridViewEx ID="gv" runat="server" AllowPaging=True AllowSorting=True 
        OnDataSourceRequested="gv_DataSourceRequested" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name"  />
        ... 
    </Columns>
</cc:GrdiViewEx>
```