# How to Sort the GridView column in ASP.net Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have created web form using master page in my Web application.And i have created GridView and i want to sort the columns.My gridview design as follows:

```
<div id="GridPopUp" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"  DataKeyNames="sno"  CssClass = "grid" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField  ItemStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox  ID="cbCheck" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="sno" HeaderText="sno"  />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="itemcode" HeaderText="ItemCode" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" IDataField="itemname" HeaderText="ItemName"  />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="unit" HeaderText="Unit"  />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="price" HeaderText="Price"  />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="qty" HeaderText="Qty"  />
         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="200px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10498012/1166719

Comment: just enable sorting on the gridview

Comment: I already did that allowsorting=true; but it shows error message

Comment: I already did that AllowSorting="True". but it shows error message "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled."I defined SortExpression="sno" and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  Pierre-Loup Pagniez and fnostro. your suggested thread is work for me.i would like to do this in without postback with help of javascrip and jquerry

Comment: Sorting a Gridview using it's built in sorting feature requires a postback each time a column header is clicked.  That said, a Gridview renders a table and there are jquery/js third party code that can handle the sorting client side with proper addition of html and or attributes.  But I would advise against it.

Comment: I did sorting a column in Gridview as shown below.Now i am using UpdatePanel for the Gridview, but it triggers postback while sorting.How can i do sorting in partial postback.@fnostro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did sorting a column in Gridview with the help of thread available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net/10498012#10498012/%22here%22)

my project coding is as follows,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvSalesItems" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="sno" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  PageSize="10" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" EnableViewState="true">
           <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>

    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:BoundField DataField="sno" HeaderText="Sno"  SortExpression="sno" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemcode" HeaderText="Item Code"  SortExpression="itemcode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item Name"  SortExpression="itemname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="unit" HeaderText="Unit"  SortExpression="unit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price"  SortExpression="price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="default_qty" HeaderText="Qty"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  />


        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind is,

```
 public void GetSalesItems() //Binding GridView
        {
                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                D.id = 2;//SELECT * from DBTABLE
                ds1 = C.DATA1(D);
                GvSalesItems.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
                GvSalesItems.DataBind();

        }
```

Codings for Sorting a GridView using ASP.net Buildin sorting functions,

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                B.id = 2;
                ds = A.DATA(B);
                GvUser.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GvUser.DataBind();

                if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
                {
                    DataView dataView = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
                    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

                    GvUser.DataSource = dataView;
                    GvUser.DataBind();
                }
            }

            private string GridViewSortDirection
            {
                get { return ViewState["SortDirection"] as string ?? "DESC"; }
                set { ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; }
            }

            private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
            {
                switch (GridViewSortDirection)
                {
                    case "ASC":
                        GridViewSortDirection = "DESC";
                        break;

                    case "DESC":
                        GridViewSortDirection = "ASC";
                        break;
                }

                return GridViewSortDirection;
            }
```

It works perfectly.I hope it will be helpful if anyone need.Thank you